# Cisco Switch Can't Ping Attached Device

Tags: cisco, vlan

```
PC1-VLAN1======Switch : Successful pings from the switch
PC1-VLAN2======Switch : *Unsuccessful* pings from the switch
```

I've got a single switch with a static IP directly connected to PC1 with a static IP, both on the same 192.168.1.0/24 network. The switch has no VLAN's on it except the default VLAN1.

With this setup, I can successfully ping PC1 from the switch (via terminal from another PC connected to the switch using either telnet or console cable).

If I Create a VLAN2 and assign PC1's port to VLAN2, the switch can no longer ping PC1. I would understand if another PC on a different VLAN couldn't ping PC1, but I would think that the switch could ping either.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It is off topic here.

Comment: I've posted the question in the networking section. Not sure why I can't delete this one, so I guess it stays.

Answer (score 0):

On the switch, the IP address that is configured is probably still in Vlan 1, move the IP to Vlan 2

If your switch IP address is 192.168.1.1

```
conf t
int vlan 1
no ip address
int vlan 2
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
end
```

Now you should be able to ping PC1 while it's in vlan 2

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I posted the question over in the networking section. http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/cisco-switch-cant-ping-attached-device. I was asking more about why the switch can't ping the attached device regardless of which VLAN it's on. It just seemed to me that if it can see it (gather stats, verify MAC address, etc) seems to me that it should be able to ping it too. The question was more about what it can and can't do in regards to VLAN's to help me better understand the separation.

Comment: Cool man, thanks for letting me know. I really like the analogy 'The VLANs are like yards separated by fences. You need a gate (router) to get from one to the other.', it's spot on :)